# Angularjs directive template transclusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an element like this:

```
<input test class="foo bar" ng-model="foo" name="foo"/>
```

And I'm trying to turn it into something like the example below, when it has the "test" attribute:

```
<div class="something">
    <input type="text" class="foo bar" ng-model="foo" name="foo"/>
    <span>test</span>
</div>
```

However I'm having problems with transclusion, instead of the attributes being transferred to the input, they get transferred to the div, so I end up with something like:

```
<div class="something foo bar" type="text" ng-model="foo" name="foo">
    <input/>
    <span>test</span>
</div>
```

Here's the directive:

```
.directive('test', [function () {
     return {
        transclude:true,
        replace:true,
        template:'<div class="something">\
            <input ng-transclude>\
            <span>hi</span>\
        </div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is possible, credits to Foxandxss from the AngularJS irc channel, for the link.

http://plnkr.co/edit/7gOQEODWlJMV9Fe9a9YV?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to transclude this way:

```
<input test class="foo bar" ng-model="foo" name="foo"/><!-- NO -->
```

I believe your best chance (with an element-level directive) is:

```
<test>
    <input class="foo bar" ng-model="foo" name="foo"/>
</test>
```

In which case the `template` of the directive would be:

```
template:
    '<div class="something">\
        <ng-transclude />\
        <span>hi</span>\
    </div>',
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this directive:

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
function myCtrl($scope){

}
app.directive("test",function(){
  return {
    template: '<div class="something"><input type="text" class="foo bar" ng-model="foo" name="foo"/><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div test ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <span>333</span>
</div>
```

Output would linke this:

```
<div class="something ng-scope" test="" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" class="foo bar ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="foo" name="foo">
  <div ng-transclude="">
    <span class="ng-scope">333</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C7Utx/)

Hope this is helpful for you